# Unity Lifecyle About Update & OnPointerClick , Who first call in the frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Unity lifecycle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

I checked the unity lifecycle , and I confuse about Update() and OnPointerClick()
Who calls first in the frame ??

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour , IPointerClickHandler
{
    // who first ??
    private void Update()
    {

    }

    // who first ??
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this yourself with something like:

```cs
private int nUpdates = 0;

private void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("Update() number: " + nUpdates);
    nUpdates += 1;
}

private void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("Update() number on click: " + nUpdates);
}
```

If, when you click, the "Update on click" message is shown first for a particular number, then that event fires first.

Let us know what turned out to be the case :-).

Spoiler:

> I'm guessing the click event will fire first, based on [the documentation from Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Comment: Thank you , IPointerClick is call first , great idea !!

[ Update() number : 84 ]
[ Update() number on click: 85 ] 
[ Update() number : 85 ]

Answer (score 2):

IPointerClick gets called in current frame as soon as you click. For better test, use below code:

```
private void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("Update frame count: " + Time.frameCount);
}

private void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("OnPointerClick frame count: " + Time.frameCount);
}
```

Comment: @MicroEyes how is it a better test? With this, we have to understand when `Time.frameCount` gets incremented. I'm not sour, just curious as to why it's better :-).

Answer (score 0):

While @AndreasHassing's and @MicroEyes' answer *will* tell you the *current* behaviour, I would strongly suggest that you try to avoid depending on **side-effects** to determine behaviour (whenever possible).

Depending on the outcome of a third party API rather than the documentation could result in a lot of confusion at a later time should they decide to internally change that behaviour.

In this case however, it is correct to say that the `Input Events` are fired before the `Update` hook gets called as you can see in the following image from the Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html):

[image: Unity Input Events vs Update Hook Execution Order]

Comment: *OnMouseXXX* is different from *IPointerClick()*

Comment: You should also know that the text displaying `OnMouseXXX` is an example of the type of event that falls under the `Input Events` category. The important thing is that `Input Events` are fired before `Game Logic` as the image illustrates.

Comment: IPointerClick() works on only UIElements and OnMouseXXX works on colliders.